# What is the glass circle in a door called?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

Some doors have a glass circle near eye level that you can look through to see what's outside. They have a fisheye effect when you look through them, with the image being most accurate in the center of the glass. Every hotel door has one.

Does anyone know what these are called?

I apologise if my tags are bad or inaccurate, or if there are better ones;  I'm not sure would tag would describe this, and it would be really hard to look through the tag list to find something specific.

Comment: Sounds like a peephole.

Comment: 'a peephole, peekhole, spyhole, doorhole, magic eye, magic mirror or door viewer is a small, round opening through a door from which a viewer on the inside of a dwelling may "peek" to see directly outside the door. The lenses are made and arranged in such a way that viewing is only possible in one direction.'

Comment: Very commonly called 'door viewers' in hardware stores here in the UK